# How to print a double in C++

Tags: c++, printing, int, double

I'm working on a C++ exercise. It requires me to print a double, But I have tried the following codes a couple times, it didn't work. How can I print the GPA as a double in the following codes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class gradeRecord{
private:
    string studentID;
    int units,gradepts;

public:    
    gradeRecord(string stuID, int unts, int gpts){
        studentID = stuID;
        units = unts;
        gradepts = gpts;
    }

    double gpa(){
        int gpa;
        gpa = double(gradepts)/units;
        return gpa;
    }

    void updateGradeInfo(int unts,int gpts){
        units = unts;
        gradepts = gpts;
    }

    void writeGradeInfo(){
        cout << "Student:" << studentID << "\t" 
            << "Unit:" << units << "\t" 
            << "GradePts:" << gradepts << "\t"
            << "GPA:" << gpa();
    }

};

int main(){
    gradeRecord studObj("783-29-4716", 100, 345);
    studObj.writeGradeInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

It comes out with the result of 
"Student:783-92-4716    Units:100    GradePts:345    GPA:3"

But what I expect is 
"Student:783-92-4716    Units:100    GradePts:345    GPA:3.45"

Instead of getting a integer in the GPA, how can I get a double?

Comment: You define `gpa` as an int, define it as a double instead

Comment: Alternative to consider - use integer math (because its easy):   int gpa = (100 * gradepts) / units;  and then 
  std::cout << (gpa / 100) << "." << (gpa % 100) << std::endl;

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: That won't turn out so well if `(gpa % 100)` is only a single digit.

Comment: @DifengChen you can check the solutions below and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @BenVoigt - intentional ... just to illustrate how easy to fix (and fix (and fix)).  
std::cout << (gpa / 100) << "." << std::setfill('0') << setw(2) << (gpa % 100) << std::setfill(' ') << std::endl;   And of course, you may want to learn about rounding ... perhaps with mili-units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can easily do by including a manipulator. This manipulator is declared in header `<iomanip>`. And set the precision directly on `std::cout` and use the `std::fixed` format specifier.

```
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

  double gpa(){
  int gpa = 100*gradepts/units;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << gpa/100.0 << '\n'; // you can set your precission to a value you plan to use
  std::cout << std::fixed;
    return gpa/100.0;
}
```

This should make your corrected work to be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision


using namespace std;
class gradeRecord{
private:
    string studentID;
    int units,gradepts;

public:    
    gradeRecord(string stuID, int unts, int gpts){
        studentID = stuID;
        units = unts;
        gradepts = gpts;
    }

      double gpa(){
      int gpa = 100*gradepts/units;
      std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << gpa/100.0 << '\n'; // you can set your precission to a value you plan to use
      std::cout << std::fixed;
        return gpa/100.0;
    }

    void updateGradeInfo(int unts,int gpts){
        units = unts;
        gradepts = gpts;
    }

    void writeGradeInfo(){
        cout << "Student:" << studentID << "\t" 
            << "Unit:" << units << "\t" 
            << "GradePts:" << gradepts << "\t"
            << "GPA:" << gpa();
    }

};

int main(){
    gradeRecord studObj("783-29-4716", 100, 345);
    studObj.writeGradeInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Instead of getting a integer in the GPA, how can I get a double?

When you use

```
    int gpa;
    gpa = double(gradepts)/units;
```

you are truncating the `double`.

If you want to keep at least two decimal points, you can use:

```
double gpa(){
    int gpa = 100*gradepts/units;
    return gpa/100.0;
}
```